# Cut off an image from the left as window size decreases CSS

Tags: css, image, background, background-image

So, right now, I have a background image that doesn't scale with the browser size, so, as you shrink the browser window, it cuts off the image on the right and remains anchored on the left. Is there any way I could edit the CSS so the right edge of the image is always on the right edge of the browser, and it cuts off the left as the window shrinks in?

After using a suggestion from below, my CSS currently looks like this:

`.header-container {
    background: url(/**/) no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 1600px;
    height: 542px;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: top right;
}`

Which is closer, but not quite right.

Comment: What browser/version are you using?

Comment: Did you ever fix this? If it's fixed either post the solution, or select an answer, so the question can be closed. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Use CSS to change the `background-position`

```
background-position: top right;
```

I tested it here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_background-position_percent

Change the code to:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body { 
    background-image: url('smiley.gif');
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: top right; 
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That's not quite doing it, it sticks to the right as the browser shrinks, which is good, but once the browser is smaller than the image, it still cuts it off from the right.

Comment: Do what I did to test it. Maybe you need `background-attachment: fixed;` ?

Comment: with the fixed attachment, the image is scaling down when the browser shrinks, even though I've got it's height hard-coded, but when I do it on the w3schools page it's behaving how I want it to. I'm adding the CSS to the question.

Comment: Everything I try in JSFiddle still works the way you want it to... Maybe try using `background-image` instead of `background`?

Comment: And add `background-repeat: no-repeat;` instead of having it in the same line?